# Re-trained keras model evaluation leaks memory when called in a loop

Tags: keras

In my application, I'm re-using the existing MobileNet trained on ImageNet and re-training the output layers on the flowers dataset with only 5 classes. The re-trained model is saved to disk. Afterwards, the model is loaded and evaluation is executed during several iterations, which eventually leads to memory exhaustion and the whole application crashes. After doing some diagnostics, I realized that the leak is coming from the model.evaluate() keras method. The issue can be reproduced in a standalone sample code:

```
import os
import resource
import keras
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_alloc = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

    for it in range(4):
        x_valid = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (64, 224, 224, 3)).astype(np.float32)
        y_valid = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.uniform(0, 5, (64, )).astype(np.int32), 5)

        start_alloc = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

        model =  keras.models.load_model(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.', 'mobilenet_flowers.h5')),
                                         custom_objects={'relu6': keras.applications.mobilenet.relu6,
                                                         'DepthwiseConv2D': keras.applications.mobilenet.DepthwiseConv2D})

        loss, _ = model.evaluate(x_valid, y_valid, batch_size=64, verbose=False)

        keras.backend.clear_session()
        del model

        end_alloc = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

        print('Iteration %d:' % it)
        print('  Memory alloc before evaluate() is %7d kilobytes'   % start_alloc)
        print('  Memory alloc after  evaluate() is %7d kilobytes'   % end_alloc)
        print('  Memory alloc loss for evaluate is %7d kilobytes\n' % (end_alloc - start_alloc))

    exit_alloc = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

    print('Memory alloc before loop is %7d kilobytes' % init_alloc)
    print('Memory alloc after  loop is %7d kilobytes' % exit_alloc)
    print('Memory alloc difference  is %7d kilobytes' % (exit_alloc - init_alloc))
```

When I execute the script, the following is printed out:

```
Iteration 0:
  Memory alloc before evaluate() is  251864 kilobytes
  Memory alloc after  evaluate() is  901696 kilobytes
  Memory alloc loss for evaluate is  649832 kilobytes

Iteration 1:
  Memory alloc before evaluate() is  901696 kilobytes
  Memory alloc after  evaluate() is 1036780 kilobytes
  Memory alloc loss for evaluate is  135084 kilobytes

Iteration 2:
  Memory alloc before evaluate() is 1036780 kilobytes
  Memory alloc after  evaluate() is 1148692 kilobytes
  Memory alloc loss for evaluate is  111912 kilobytes

Iteration 3:
  Memory alloc before evaluate() is 1148692 kilobytes
  Memory alloc after  evaluate() is 1190804 kilobytes
  Memory alloc loss for evaluate is   42112 kilobytes

Memory alloc before loop is  138792 kilobytes
Memory alloc after  loop is 1190804 kilobytes
Memory alloc difference  is 1052012 kilobytes
```

Any suggestions what may be wrong here? After going through the forums, I tried adding K.clear_session(), but, as you can see in the code, that didn't help. The model is stored temporary at https://ufile.io/rgaxs.

Some additional info about my environment:

```
== cat /etc/issue ===============================================
Linux 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial

== are we in docker =============================================
No

== compiler =====================================================
c++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

== check pips ===================================================
numpy (1.12.1)
numpydoc (0.7.0)
protobuf (3.5.0)
tensorflow (1.4.0)
tensorflow-tensorboard (0.4.0rc3)

== check for virtualenv =========================================
False

== tensorflow import ============================================
tf.VERSION = 1.4.0
tf.GIT_VERSION = v1.4.0-rc1-11-g130a514
tf.COMPILER_VERSION = v1.4.0-rc1-11-g130a514
keras.VERSION = 2.0.9
```

Comment: I have the same problem with tensorflow.keras (v. 1.12). Are there any news? Did you solve it eventually?