# CPU usage and time until training starts increasing on each model.fit() in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created an LSTM with Keras API. Now I am facing an issue while I try to test different values in it (for learning rate f.e.). Each time I change my values and define the model new somehow the model takes longer and longer until training start the CPU usage in waiting time is at 100%. Am I doing something wrong so that older learning session effect the new models?

My code is structered as followed, in one file I call a evaluation with different values and many iterations like this:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    acc = model.create(xtrain, ytrain, hidden_units=hidden_size, batch_size=batch_size, learning_rate=learning_rate, l2_reg=l2_reg)
```

model is another file. In there I use the passed values to train a new model and pass back the accuracy to find the best batch size etc. Tho code for model creation is something like:

```
def create(xtrain, ytrain, hidden_units, batch_size, learning_rate, l2_reg):
    # defining some layers from input to output
    # example: input = Input(shape=(20,)) ...

    # creating the model
    model = Model(inputs=[input], output=[outputs])
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

    # calling model.fit
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', patience=4, verbose=1)
    model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(some_xval_data, some_yval_data), callbacks=[es])

    ## In the end I evaluate the model on unseen data and return the accuracy
    loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_testdata, y_testdata, batch_size=batch_size)
    return acc
```

Now everytime the model starts to train the script prints:

```
Epoch 1/100
```

On the first evaluation calls the model instantly starts to train and I see the time it takes for each step. But after some time, after the print of "Epoch 1/100" it suddenly starts to take time until the training starts. And the time increases from call to call. While it is waiting for the training to really start I can observe that my CPU usage is at 100% in that time.

So am I doing it wrong in calling the method every time again? Is there some process there older calls of "create" effect newer ones? I just hope that older training is not effecting newer training in my code structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Fedor Petrov and @desertnaut.

They discussed in the comments of another answer that I have to call the function `clear_session`:

```
from keras.backend import clear_session

def create():
    # do all the model stuff
    # evaluate the model
    clear_session() 
    return
```

Now I can call `create()` as many times as I want without any memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Exploding memory usage during evaluation is already a known issue.
[Re-trained keras model evaluation leaks memory when called in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920077/re-trained-keras-model-evaluation-leaks-memory-when-called-in-a-loop)
One notices it typically when the evaluation is done periodically in a callback. In your case you just call evaluate(...) 100 times which is also enough to observe the problem.

Since I trained my models in the cloud, I "solved" a similar problem just by increasing RAM of the instance.

UPD. 
This was my knowledge some time ago. Fruitful discussion below resulted in the following answer (as stated here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2102):

```
   keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Running this you remove the unnecessary information from your tf.Graph

Comment: A link to an unanswered SO question arguably does not qualify for labeling some behavior as a "known bug"; any links to Github issues?

Comment: You are right it's not a bug, it's a behaviour of Keras with TF backend.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2102
Can be solved by clearing session.

Comment: Good job - the thread already contains some possible remedies (`K.clear_session()`); I suggest you update your post to include *this* link, as well as possible remedies inspired from there...

Comment: I think that's the solution. I was not running clear_session() oO

Comment: @FedorPetrov as you can see, the answer was arguably just one step away :)